# Wifi work after disable eth0

Tags: networking, wifi

I have problem to connect on internet over Wi-Fi.
Cable is not connected.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

After command `$ ifdown eth0` internet working.

File `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.80/24
    network 192.168.0.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
    dns-options rotate

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

How to change configuration, to work over cable if cable is connected and work over Wi-Fi if cable is not connected ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to change configuration" **SIMPLE** revert to the default settings  which work out of the box. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697).

If you **REALLY** must use static do it properly!